# Using XPath in node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, dom, xpath

I am building a little document parser in node.js. To test, I have [a raw HTML file](https://gist.github.com/dend/b0148c00b501859a5eb3bb2b310ad1f7), that is generally downloaded from the real website when the application executes.

I want to extract the **first** code example from each section of the Console.WriteLine that matches my constraint - it has to be written in C#. To do that, I have this sample XPath:

```
//*[@id='System_Console_WriteLine_System_String_System_Object_System_Object_System_Object_']/parent::div/following-sibling::div/pre[position()>1]/code[contains(@class,'lang-csharp')]
```

If I [test the XPath online](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi), I get the expected results, which [is in this Gist](https://gist.github.com/dend/1a3477773286075b90b20472439ee2ed).

In my node.js application, I am using [xmldom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xmldom) and [xpath](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xpath) to try and parse that exact same information out:

```
var exampleLookup = `//*[@id='System_Console_WriteLine_System_String_System_Object_System_Object_System_Object_']/parent::div/following-sibling::div/pre[position()>1]/code[contains(@class,'lang-csharp')]`;
var doc = new dom().parseFromString(rawHtmlString, 'text/html');
var sampleNodes = xpath.select(exampleLookup,doc);
```

This does not return anything, however.

What might be going on here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is most likely caused by the default namespace (`xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"`) in your HTML (XHTML).

Looking at the [xpath docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xpath#namespaces-with-easy-mappings), you should be able to bind the namespace to a prefix using `useNamespaces` and use the prefix in your xpath (untested)...

```
var exampleLookup = `//*[@id='System_Console_WriteLine_System_String_System_Object_System_Object_System_Object_']/parent::x:div/following-sibling::x:div/x:pre[position()>1]/x:code[contains(@class,'lang-csharp')]`;
var doc = new dom().parseFromString(rawHtmlString, 'text/html');
var select = xpath.useNamespaces({"x": "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"});
var sampleNodes = xpath.select(exampleLookup,doc);
```

Instead of binding the namespace to a prefix, you could also use `local-name()` in your XPath, but I wouldn't recommend it. This is also covered [in the docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xpath#namespaces).

Example...

```
//*[@id='System_Console_WriteLine_System_String_System_Object_System_Object_System_Object_']/parent::*[local-name()='div']/following-sibling::*[local-name()='div']/*[local-name()='pre'][position()>1]/*[local-name()='code'][contains(@class,'lang-csharp')]
```

Comment: "This is most likely caused by the default namespace". What should it be instead? What is "x" in your example?

Comment: @DesignbyAdrian - An xml namespace that's declared without a prefix to bind to (like `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"`) is said to be a [default namespace](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/#defaulting). It's not that it should be something else instead. The "x" is the arbitrary prefix that I used to bind the namespace uri (`http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml`) to. It could've been `xhtml`, `foo`, or any other valid prefix name (NCName; [see here](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/#ns-decl)).

Answer (score 3):

There is a library [`xpath-html`](https://github.com/hieuvp/xpath-html) that can help you using XPath to query HTML, with minimal efforts and lines of code.

```js
const fs = require("fs");
const html = fs.readFileSync(`${__dirname}/shopback.html`, "utf8");

const xpath = require("xpath-html");
const node = xpath.fromPageSource(html).findElement("//*[contains(text(), 'with love')]");

console.log(`The matched tag name is "${node.getTagName()}"`);
console.log(`Your full text is "${node.getText()}"`);
```